# selecting data from dropdown without refreshing the page

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my application,when I am selecting the category from drop down(ddlcategory) ,the data will bind in the purity dropdown(ddlpurity).But the page is refreshing.So I used update panel to solve this(page refreshing) problem.Now the data is not binding to the ddlpurity ,when data from ddlcategory is selected.How can i bind the data to ddlpurity without refreshing the page.

**asp design page**

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"> </asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" id="UpdatePanel" updatemode="Conditional">
 <Triggers>
     <asp:Asyncpostbacktrigger controlid="ddlcategory" eventname="SelectedIndexChanged" />
   </Triggers>
       <ContentTemplate>
             <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlcategory" class="form-control txtboxmargin validate[required]" runat="server" 
               AutoPostBack="True" onselectedindexchanged="ddlcategory_SelectedIndexChanged" AppendDataBoundItems="True">
             <asp:ListItem Value="">--select category--</asp:ListItem>
           </asp:DropDownList>
       </ContentTemplate>

   </asp:UpdatePanel>

<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlpurity" 
               class="form-control txtboxmargin" AutoPostBack="True" runat="server"
               onselectedindexchanged="ddlpurity_SelectedIndexChanged">
           </asp:DropDownList>
```

**C# code:**

```
protected void ddlcategory_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ddlcategory.SelectedItem.Text == "Gold")
        {
            BindDDLGoldPurity();
            lblheadpurity.Text = "ADD GOLD PURITY";
            txtsalesrate.ReadOnly = true;

        }
        if (ddlcategory.SelectedItem.Text == "Silver")
        {
            BindDDLSilverPurity();
            lblheadpurity.Text = "ADD SILVER PURITY";
            txtsalesrate.ReadOnly = true;

        }
        if (ddlcategory.SelectedItem.Text == "Gemstones")
        {
            txtsalesrate.ReadOnly = false;
            txtsalesrate.Text = "";

            ddlpurity.Items.Clear();

        }

    }
```

Comment: put them both in the same update panel

Comment: as said by @Jeremy, you need to add both the `dropdownlist` inside update panel. And on additional part set _AutoPostBack=false_ of both the dropdownlist

Comment: But if i am adding labels(lblcategory,lblpurity) it shows "An extender can't be in a different UpdatePanel than the control it extends."

Answer (score 0):

Set AutoPostBack="False" to get rid of the refreshing behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

You should *wrap* both the controls inside the `UpdatePanel`.

On the Second part. Remove

```
AutoPostBack="true"
```

from your `DropDownList`.

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="UpdatePanel" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ddlcategory" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
    </Triggers>
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlcategory" class="form-control txtboxmargin validate[required]"
            runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlcategory_SelectedIndexChanged"
            AppendDataBoundItems="True">
            <asp:ListItem Value="">--select category--</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlpurity" class="form-control txtboxmargin" AutoPostBack="True"
            runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlpurity_SelectedIndexChanged">
        </asp:DropDownList>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Also you can use [javascript/jquery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to perform database request.

See the [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13563750/how-to-avoid-page-refresh-on-select-of-dropdownlist)

Comment: but it is showing error..we can't include div inside it??

Comment: Error :"An extender can't be in a different UpdatePanel than the control it extends."

Comment: can you show the code which you tried in a js fiddle

Comment: <div class="row"> <div class="col-md-6">
     <asp:Label ID="lblpurity" runat="server" Text="Purity"></asp:Label>
 </div><div class="col-md-6">
       <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlpurity" 
                   class="form-control txtboxmargin" AutoPostBack="True" runat="server" 
                   onselectedindexchanged="ddlpurity_SelectedIndexChanged">
               </asp:DropDownList>
                 <asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtnaddpurity" Tooltip="Add Purity" runat="server"  Height="30px"  Width="30px" ImageUrl="~/Images/addmorered.png" />
           </div>
         </div>

Comment: Is your label inside or outside the panel ? See [this](http://forums.asp.net/t/1037477.aspx?+An+extender+can+t+be+in+a+different+UpdatePanel+than+the+control+it+extends+error+really+needs+debugging+information)